# Casting object to System.Linq.Enumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method that takes in an object that does a copy of that object using Json.Net to serialize and deserialize that object. It looks like this:

```
internal static object Clone(this object parameter)
{
    var type = parameter.GetType();
    var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameter);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializedObject, type);
}
```

The problem I have it that I don't have any control over what objects are passed into this. And if someone for example does something like this:

```
var result = myListOfStrings.Select(x => x);
result.Clone();
```

The object passed in will be of type WhereSelectListIterator`2

I realize that if I just did

```
result.ToList().Clone();
```

The problem would be solved. However the setup is alot more complex than described here and I simply can not control what it passed into Clone. So in my Clone() method I would like to be able to check if the parameter is some sort of Enumerable and if so do a "ToList()" on it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have to support callers that pass you non-cloneable objects? Seems like the most obvious solution to this issue is simply to not support that particular use of your method. Make the caller do the conversion to something serializable, if they want to start with an iterator like that.

Comment: That's because of "lazy execution". Try search that phrase.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I could set limits, yes, but as far as I know I can't stop their code from compiling. So I would have to rely on people using it to read documentation and that's never a good bet!

Comment: @NathanGong: I'm aware of that, and I need to a way to check the type so that I can execute it before I process it.

Comment: @ds99jove: except that there are always going to be limits. No matter how much effort you put into supporting various scenarios, someone can always come up with an object you can't handle. There are just too many commonly-used types that would require some special handling. There's a reason that the .NET serialization APIs all have significant constraints on what can be serialized by default, requiring the _caller_ to write custom code to handle the non-simple scenarios.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this helps you refactor your method.

```
internal static object Clone(this object parameter)
{
    if (parameter is IEnumerable)
        parameter = (parameter as IEnumerable).Cast<object>().ToList();

    var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameter);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializedObject, parameter.GetType());
}
```

Comment: `Cast<IEnumerable>()` looks suspicious to me. Do you mean `Cast<object>()` ?

Comment: Works! I tried doing parameter.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEnumerable)) which did not work. This did though :) Thank you!

Comment: Note the `is`/`as` anti-pattern here though. The basic idea is right, but there's no point using `is` in code that's just going to immediately use `as` right after. Instead, just use `as` and check for null.

Comment: Only problem I see with this solution is that a IEnumerable<string> will come out as IEnumerable<object>. I think this still works for me though.

Comment: This also catches strings and produces a array of characters when deserializing. WIll have to unmark answer.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand something since
`string str = "abcdefg"; var clone = str.Clone(); // clone is string => true`